# Failed to download Cherrypy 3.1.2

Tags: python, python-2.6, cherrypy

I am trying to download cherrypy 3.1.2 onto my windows laptop installed with python 2.6 but when I try easy_install cherrypy==3.1.2 and get this

```
Searching for cherrypy==3.1.2
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/cherrypy/
Reading http://download.cherrypy.org/cherrypy/2.2.1/
Reading http://download.cherrypy.org/cherrypy/2.3.0/
Reading http://download.cherrypy.org/cherrypy/3.0.0/
Reading http://download.cherrypy.org/cherrypy/3.0.1/
Reading http://download.cherrypy.org/cherrypy/3.0.2/
Reading http://download.cherrypy.org/cherrypy/3.0.3/
Reading http://download.cherrypy.org/cherrypy/3.0.4/
Reading http://download.cherrypy.org/cherrypy/3.0RC1/
Reading http://download.cherrypy.org/cherrypy/3.1.0/
Reading http://download.cherrypy.org/cherrypy/3.1.0beta3/
Reading http://download.cherrypy.org/cherrypy/3.1.0rc1/
Reading http://download.cherrypy.org/cherrypy/3.1.1/
Reading http://download.cherrypy.org/cherrypy/3.1.2/
Reading http://download.cherrypy.org/cherrypy/3.1beta/
Reading http://download.cherrypy.org/cherrypy/3.2.0/
Reading http://download.cherrypy.org/cherrypy/3.2.2/
Reading http://download.cherrypy.org/cherrypy/3.2.3/
Reading http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=56099
Reading http://trac.cherrypy.org/cgi-bin/trac.cgi/wiki/CherryPyDownload
Reading http://www.cherrypy.org
Download error on http://www.cherrypy.org: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed -- S
ome packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for cherrypy==3.1.2
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('cherrypy==3.1
.2')
```

Please help

Comment: Either the DNS server or the domain cherrypy.org or your internet connection is not working properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/issue/1359/cherrypy-31x-no-longer-installs-via-pypi). :(

You can add a comment on the bug and meanwhile download the tar/zip/installer from the [internet archive.](https://web.archive.org/web/20131225053209/http://download.cherrypy.org/CherryPy/3.1.2/)

Comment: Thanks @cyraxjoe, I have managed to get the installer from the internet archive and it has worked

Answer (score 1):

For next readers, `pip install cherrypy==3.1.2` now works (and also for some of 2.x releases). Sylvain has closed the issue.

Also as long as there're no plans to drop Python 2.6 support for CherryPy 3.x, and if you don't rely on some very specific behaviour of the old version, it's better to use latest available one.